# In React, how to properly setState within a .map function to limit parallel HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, state, setstate

So basically, i have a component "ShowTaskStatus" that will show how many tasks are open, how many closed and the total. This result i get by POSTing to my query server endpoint. 
In my dashboard, ShowTaskStatus can be rendered multiple times and the results will be visible per row in a table. There can be up to 50 different areas, and the query is quite complex. The result per row is presented as soon as the result is available, without waiting for the other areas to be fetched.

## **Dashboard**

### Area | Open | Closed | Total

- Area1 | 10 | 20 | 30
- Area2 | 12 | 28 | 40
- AreaX | XX | YY | ZZ
- ...

So the problem is, that the process that handles the query cannot handle that many request and i want to limit therefore how many "active" HTTPMethods can be executed before fetching a new Area.

```
//initial queryProcs = 0

var that = this;

var areaRows = areas.map(function(area) {

  //some other code

  isLoading[area] = true;
  this.setState({ 
    isLoading : isLoading 
  });

  // so check how many requests are running
  if (that.state.queryProcs < 5) {

    // only after state is set, execute POST
    that.setState({
      queryProcs: queryProcs + 1,
    }, () => {
      POST('/TastStatus', queryParameters, function(response) {

          // This code is executed when POST returns a response
          //dome something here

          isLoading[area] = false;

          //trigger a rerender by setting state with the query result
          //and also decrease the counter so another free query process is available
          that.setState(prevState => ({ 
            queryProcs: prevState.queryProcs - 1,
            isLoading: isLoading
            //...
          }));

      }, function(error, errorText) {
          //some error handling

          //free up another query process
          self.setState(prevState => ({ 
            queryProcs: prevState.queryProcs - 1,
            //...
          }));  
      });
    })
  }
});
```

so obviously this is not working, as the state will never have the chance to be up-to-date during the map loop and the POST response anyway comes asynchronous.

Well i guess i could just build up my data within the map and setState outside of it. The data will then hold the complete result of all areas, but i will loose my "line-by-line" result loading feature.

Has someone a suggestion here?

Comment: i think usign react state to store counters and other configuration variables is not correct as state controls component rendering and what you need are only global flags that control query execution. Better have global flags controlling this (not state as will trigger re-rendering) and have each query check the global flags whether it can execute the query now or set a timeout for re-checking if query can be executed later on. This will save both time and resources and will have better flow. Also using redux here might be an option, but not needed

Comment: ok yes, you are right, i can use a global counter this make sense. I just noticed that i have another problem. So when the limit is, let say 1, the condition will pass only one POST, then the other areas within the map will not fulfil the condition and no POST is triggered anymore. So when the result of the first POST revieces a response, the rerender will take place but the other areas are gone.

Comment: you can trigger a re-render of each area ONLY WHEN the respective query has been executed and completed. No need to lose the other areas, if you are having this problem somethign is wrong with your design

Answer (score 0):

i have not found a solution for this, propably -as Nikos told in his comments- its not best practice anyway.

I have rewritten the code now to fill up an queue array instead. This queue will then be processed by a thread function that is called and checked via timeout.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you are using any global state management like 'redux' along with react. you can get the control of rendering the components, according to the responses by updating that global state.